# How can I monitor the system tray icon notification once it pops up using python in Windows10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7, system-tray

I want to set an SMS alert once a system tray popup message appears on my windows system. What are the ways to monitor the system tray icon popup messages on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

Either create your own custom handler for creating notifications, or track changes in tray icons.
Libraries: win32file, win32con, win32gui.
Maybe you can help: [GitHub](https://github.com/timeyyy/system_tray/blob/master/system_tray/tray2.py)
The task is interesting.